# Guidance on creating Custom User Models in Django

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-models, oauth

I would like to create a registration for users for a fashion-tech application, using facebook login as well as an optional email/password login/signup.

I am stuck on how to finish the process (too many examples from blogs telling me contradicting information and the Django docs doesnt explain what I need very clearly).

So my questions are:

1. How can I create my model to show users being able to login/signup via a custom designing interface(by me), while prohibiting them from logging in the Admin User area and being a superuser, but allowing me(the Admin) to view and control the users in the regular django admin area for superusers.

I am guessing I must first start with the models/logic first so:

Here is my models.py so far I have added the fields for the users, that they will have access from their profiles once logged in officially. But of course first they will be asked to login in(if the choose the password/email login or signup) with their email, username and password.

## Models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models

#custom user model fro Users

class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, db_index=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, null=False, unique=True, blank=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    

user_title = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    user_points = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=True)
    avatar = FileField()

    #admin level and additional infomation
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)


USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'username']


class MyUserManager(object):
    """Creates and saves a User with the given first_name, last_name, birthday,"""
    def create_user(self, email, username, first_name, last_name, birthday, city, state, use

r_title, user_points, avatar, password=None):
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

    user = self.model(
        email=MyUserManager.normalize_email(email),
        first_name=first_name,
        last_name=last_name,
        birthday=birthday,
        city=city
        state=state,
        user_title=user_title,
        user_points=user_points,
        avatar=avatar,
    )

    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_superuser(self,  email, first_name, last_name, birthday, city, state, user_title, user_points, avatar, password):
    

user = self.create_user(email,
        password=password,
        first_name=first_name,
        last_name=last_name,
        birthday=birthday,
        city=city
        state=state,
        user_title=user_title,
        user_points=user_points,
        avatar=avatar,
    )


    user =
```

Comment: Don't create your own user model, create a userprofile and use a `OneToOneField` with the django `User` object. Then everything will work out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your custom user model looks fine to me from first glance.

To properly integrate the custom model with the Django admin, you should replace the `is_admin` field to two fields which are used by Django admin `is_staff` and `is_superuser`. For more details [see the documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-django-contrib-admin). This will prevent non-staff (not admin) users from accessing the admin, as well as allow you to define a superuser to grant full access to.

EDIT: simpler method found, simply subclass AbstractUser and not AbstractBaseUser, this is detailed [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user). Here is your code, modified and cleared of any redundant fields (that are already implemented in the parent class)

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    birthday = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

    user_title = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    user_points = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=True)
    avatar = models.FileField()
```

Now, to finish the process you only need to write the urls and views for your pages, and use the [@login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required) decorator where appropriate, to prevent ["anonymous" users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#anonymous-users) from accessing those pages.

Example view that implements the @login_required decorator:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render

@login_required
def user_profile(request):
    # render your template with the RequestContext
    return render('profile.html')
```

Comment: could you possibly expand on this with a code example? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I've added some code samples as well as a easier way to create a custom user model with admin access. If you need help with other misc. Django how to, please follow [django's tutorials](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/overview/)